# Can't use filter with dynamic linq

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I tried to use ef plus for filtering data with following code

```
_context.Filter<TEntity>(x => x.Where(q => "q.Property == 1"));
```

And got an error.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What was the error message you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval-Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

As specified in the introduction: http://entityframework-plus.net/linq-dynamic, LINQ Dynamic require the library Eval-Expression.NET (paid library) to work.

It should now work once you add this library in reference: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.Expressions.Eval/